# Is it worth to submit informal comments on the written opinion of the International Searching Authority?

Tags: pct, search-report, written, comments

As per the PCT Guide,

> the purpose of such informal comments is to give the applicant an
> opportunity to rebut the written opinion of the International
> Searching Authority in the event that international preliminary
> examination is not requested.

However it seems there will be no comment or rebuttal from any office of the PCT and these comments **may** be (or may be not) considered in the national phase for each examiner.

Answer (score 3):

My personal experience is that informal comments have never improved our position in any way. In the national/regional phases, the same objections have been raised by the same patent office acting as ISA, and by other patent offices.